# Spring MVC Rest, invoking using URL, escape characters &amp; causing issue for getting the value in controller

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a controller mapping as below

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/search"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody
 Object searchProducts(@PathVariable("query") String query,
 @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) String param1,
 @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) String param2,)
```

when i use url as given below it works fine i even get the value populated by spring

```
 http://host/app_name/search?param1=[value]&param2=[value]
```

But when escape character is used it breaks

```
 http://host/app_name/search?param1=[value]&amp;param2=[value]
```

Is there any configuration in springcontext or web.xml which will allow me to take care of encoding automatically ??
i have already tried setting below contect in web.xml but it does not work

```
 <context-param> 
 <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name> 
 <param-value>true</param-value> 
 </context-param>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to pass `&amp;` in URL?

Comment: I am passing multiple request parameters,  the standard way

Comment: parameters standard way url?param1=value1&param2=value2 , but when a user enters or invokes through a internal system, sometimes it has "&amp;" which is escape character for '&' which spring ignores or treates as part of value.

Answer (score 3):

`&amp;` is an HTML escape sequence, and there are no requirements to treat it as `&` in URLs. Therefore it would be better to fix your internal system in order to make it generate correct URLs.

However, if you cannot do it for some reason, you can solve this problem in the following (hackish) way:

- Create a `Filter` that would wrap original `HttpServlerRequest` into your subclass of `HttpServlerRequestWrapper`.
- In that subclass create a map of "fixed" parameters (i.e. get parameters from the original request and create a new parameter map by stripping `amp;` from the begining of parameter names) and override `getParameter*()` methods to use that map.

Comment: Wow, we posted basically the exact same thing =(

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, it helped me a lot. we will error out html escape sequence

Answer (score 2):

Would make sense that Spring would treat it as part of the value, `'&amp;'` is HTML encoded, not URL encoded.

I would try to figure out why the system is HTML encoding the `'&'` as `'&amp;'` rather than building a proper GET string.

If you want to actually include an ampersand within the value of GET parameters, use %26 which decodes into '&' when passed through a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(query);
```